# Class not found on Laravel - Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Getting an error -  **Class 'Ientry' not found** on Laravel 5.6. while running page 
**localhost/work/i-upload-panel**

My **route.php** code is below

```
Route::get('/i-upload-panel', function () {
    (new  Ientry())->importToDb();
        dd('done');
        return view('admin.i-upload-panel');
}
);
```

Model **Ientry.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Ientry extends Model
{
     public function importToDb()
     {
        //Function here
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `Ientry` any library?

Comment: @DilipHirapara No, It is a Model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said it is model then you have to use a namespace with the model then you can create instance of that class.

```
(new App\Http\Model\Ientry())->importToDb();
```

or

```
(new \App\Http\Model\Ientry())->importToDb();
```

Comment: Glad to help you happy coding :)

Comment: Must've beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks you're attempting to use an imported as opposed to a fully qualified reference to it. The route files don't normally have a namespace declaration, so the best bet would be to explicitly reference.

It would be something like:

```
(new \App\Model\Ientry())->importToDb();
```

Comment: he defined namespace as `\App\Http\Model\`